# How to make different colors in line and marker

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I plot two figures using:

```
x=linspace(-5,5,10); 
y1=2*x;
y2=x.^2;
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(x,y1,'sr-');
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(x,y2,'b-o');
```

I want to make the marker and line have different colors, like a red line and black marker in 1st figure. However, using the above both line and marker have the same color. How can I make the markers have different colors from the line?

[image]

Comment: From MATLAB's [Line Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.line-properties.html): `Color`, `MarkerEdgeColor`, `MarkerFaceColor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a `'MarkerEdgeColor'` name-value pair to your `plot()` command:

```
x=linspace(-5,5,10);
y1=2*x;
y2=x.^2;
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(x,y1,'sr-','MarkerEdgeColor','b');
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(x,y2,'b-o','MarkerEdgeColor','r');
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Note that I coloured the line the "usual" way, by including either `'r'` or `'b'` in the initial command, and manually changed the marker colour. Take a peek at the documentation on [line properties](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.line-properties.html) for all the parameters you can tune for a line.

Answer (score 1):

Adding more parameter like `LineWidth`, `MarkerSize` and `MarkerFacecolor` helped:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lets unpack your commands:

you are asking `sr-` to your plot, i.e.   "square, red, line". If we break this into "square, " and "red, line", you can have exactly the effect you want:

```
hold on
plot(x,y1,'r-');
plot(x,y1,'sb');
```

Alternatively use @Adriaan's suggestion, but the final effect is slightly different.

Comment: Breaking it down is clearer, but you'd create double the amount of line-objects, cluttering your figure handles down the line.

Comment: @Adriaan Sure, I'd go with your suggestion! I was trying to add a little extra for educational purposes ;). However, double amount of line objects is maybe not true. I still plot 1)line 2)markers. You just do it with one call to `plot`, but the amount of objects its the same.